# Jersey empty/null payload

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I have next endpoint:

```
@POST
@Path("{id}/chechout")
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response checkout(@PathParam("id") String id, Checkout checkout)
```

it successfully works when I POST payload

```
{ "payByCard":true}
```

but I want to have possibility to POST empty/null payload, in which case payByCard will have default value "false".

Now it just throws `java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input`

Comment: What are you using to deserialize the Checkout object(Jackson\Gson)? you have to modify it so that it can be initialized from a null json - post the code for the Checkout object